# Javascript Inner array updated by outside code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code to iterate & add some values to my accordionData;

```
var confPanels = {};
confPanels.accordionPanels = [];
confPanels.accordionPanels.length = 0;


self.get('accordionData').forEach(function(accordionData) {
    var grid = {};
    gridCols = self.gridParams(accordionData); // gridCols is returned as an object containing arrays
    debugger; // Here when I come during the 2nd iteration, the earlier value in confPanels.accordionPanels[0].panel.props[0].value is overwritten to the new value (i.e. value corresponding to the 2nd iteration. Why is that so ?)
    confPanels.accordionPanels.push({
        panel: {
            name: "my-grid",
            props: [{
                key: 'params',
                value: gridCols
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

My question is as I iterate through accordionData & have a call to gridParams() to get the corresponding gridCols.

For the below scenario, as I debug & during the 2nd iteration, the earlier value in confPanels.accordionPanels[0].panel.props[0].value is overwritten to the new value (i.e. value corresponding to the 2nd iteration. Why is that so ?)

Comment: have you tried with `var gridCols = self.gridParams(accordionData);`

Comment: Yes, tried that already...same thing happens

Comment: is it a async call?

Comment: This code is after the AJAX response is already received...so no async call within this code